# How to connect two different Tab bar icons to same view controller with storyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

I have a tab bar controller in an iPad app with 6 items. Two of the icons will when you tap at them lead to the same view controller. This view controller has a list of items it will show, it will change slightly depending on which of the tab bar icons you tapped.

How do i set this up with storyboards? Its possible to drag the relationship twice to the same view controller, but then it just shows two of the same icons on the tab bar. I want the two choices to have different icons and name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like you've found, you can design the view controller once in the storyboard but won't be able to associate it with the tab bar controller more than once.

What you can do is assign an identifier for it in the identity inspector, and then at runtime you can use the method [-[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStoryboard/instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier%3a) to instantiate a second copy of the view controller. You can insert that second copy into the tab controller using [-[UITabBarController setViewControllers:animated:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're better off creating two separate view controllers and placing them in the Tab Bar Controller individually, especially if they're going to load different data. You can place the same view controller into a Tab Bar Controller multiple times, but as far as design goes and how you can manipulate it, it won't make much sense to do it that way.

Comment: Its the same data, just a different subset. So they will look 100 % the same

Comment: Understood, but the Tab Bar Controller is really only meant to select between different view controllers, not subsets of data.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same question as yours when I am trying to implement a tab bar controller view with 4 tab items, and each tab item reusing the same view controller, and the custom logic for these 4 items are set through the property when the tab bar controller call `viewDidLoad`. Let me show you what I have done as below:

**1. Create a Tab Bar Controller with 4 view controllers**

Open the storyboard, and drag a `Tab Bar Controller` from the object library. And drag another 2 more `view controller` onto the storyboard as well.

Remember to make a linkage between the tab bar controller and the 2 new view controller.

**2. Create a reusing view controller for the 4 tab view**

Create a new cocoa touch class, named `ViewController`, and create you customisation properties in the @interface section. These properties will be set in the tab bar controller `viewDidLoad` method, so the 4 tab views will use the same view controller, but the properties are not the same.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

// Define your customisation properties here, so that you can set it in the tab bar controller.
@property (assign, nonatomic) UITableViewCellStyle style;

@end
```

**4. Create a view controller subclass of UITabBarController**

Create a new Cocoa Touch class, named `UITabViewController`, and make it subclass of `UITabBarController`, and conform `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

For my case, I need to show a table view with different 4 cell style in 4 different tabs, so I will set the `viewController`'s `style` property in the tab bar controller to achieve my target.

**UITabViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITabViewController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@end
```

**UITabViewController.m**

```
#import "UITabViewController.h"

@interface UITabViewController ()

@end

@implementation UITabViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Make UITabViewController as the delegate of UITabBarController
    self.delegate = self;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set-Up the UITableCell style for each tab item
    [self.viewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id viewController, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
        UITableViewCellStyle style;
        switch (idx) {
            case 0:
                style = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
                break;
            case 1:
                style = UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle;
                break;
            case 2:
                style = UITableViewCellStyleValue1;
                break;
            case 3:
                style = UITableViewCellStyleValue2;
                break;
            default:
                style = UITableViewCellStyleDefault;
                break;
        }

        SEL selector = @selector(setStyle:);

        if([viewController respondsToSelector:selector]){
            NSInvocation *invk = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[viewController methodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
            [invk setSelector:selector];
            [invk setTarget:viewController];

            [invk setArgument:&style atIndex:2];
            [invk invoke];
        }
    }];
}
```

Or if you need to set the customisation properties when the user selected different tab items, then you can add a new delegate method in the `UITabViewController` @implementation section:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    // Check whether the view controller responds to the property setter method
    SEL selector = @selector(setMyProperty:);

    if([viewController respondsToSelector:selector]){
        // Call the setter method with NSInvocation
        NSInvocation *invk = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[viewController methodSignatureForSelector:selector]];
        [invk setSelector:selector];
        [invk setTarget:viewController];

        [invk setArgument:&argument atIndex:2];
        [invk invoke];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it quite easily.

Create a TabBarController in the Storyboard.

In each tab assign a Navigation controller.

Make all Navigation controllers set as Root View Controller the one view controller you want to share between them.

In your View Controller, in ViewDidLoad, create a condition based on the tabBarController.selectedIndex in order to customize the view controller depending on the selected tab. Something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let selectedTabIndex = tabBarController?.selectedIndex {
           switch selectedTabIndex:
           case 0: // Customize ViewController for tab 1
           case 1: // Customize ViewController for tab 2
           case 2: // Customize ViewController for tab 3
           default: break

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you're trying to do with a UITabBarController. You can add two different instance of the same view controller class if you want. Otherwise, you would have to add a tab bar to a regular UIViewController, and write your own logic to switch between controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by setting the tab titles in viewDidLoad.  I created 2 relationships to the same View Controller. I then set the Bar Item Title to "Not Set".  Finally, I set the viewDidLoad method as follows:

```
  UITabBarController *tc = (UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController;
  NSArray *vcs = tc.viewControllers;
  BOOL tabsInitialized=YES;
  for (UIViewController *vc in vcs)
  {
    if ([vc.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"Not Set"])
    {
      tabsInitialized = NO;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!tabsInitialized)
  {
    int I=1;
    for (UIViewController *vc in vcs)
    {
      vc.tabBarItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tab %i", i++];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was answered a while ago, but none of the solutions mentioned using a `UITabBar` directly and overriding its `UITabBarDelegate` `tabBar(:,didSelect item:)` method, rather than let a `UITabBarController` handle the selection indirectly.

```
extension MyListViewController: UITabBarDelegate {

    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        // Set some filter based on the selected item or its tag (tag values can be assigned in IB)
        switch item.tag {
            // Apply filter to your datasource based on the item.tag
        }

        // Or if you are using a CoreData NSFetchedResultsController, set its predicate:
        // resultsController.predicate = makePredicate(item.tag)
        // resultsController.performFetch()

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

By overriding `UITabBarDelegate` methods directly, you are in direct control of the selection behavior of the tab. So you could re-use the same instance of your `UIViewController` instead of the `UITabBarController` insistently creating a new instance of the `UIViewController` for each tab. For example, in the `didSelect` method, you could apply a filter to an existing list of items in a `UITableView` instead of creating a new instance of the list in a new `UITableView` as the other solutions do.

**Note:** If you use a `UITabBar` in your view controller in code or in IB, UIKit does not seem to recognize its presence and "underlapping" scroll views (e.g. `UITableView`, `UICollectionView`) will not automatically adjust their `contentInset`. Nor will anchoring the bottom of the `UITabBar` lay itself out properly on a device with non-zero safe area margins if you anchor it to the bottom of of the safe area (it will appear to "float" with a gap between itself and the screen-edge).

**Solution (part 1):** Set the top constraint specially on the `UITabBar` instance: First anchor the *bottom* edge of the tab bar to the `Superview` and anchor the *top* edge to the **bottom** edge of the **Safe Area** and set the constant to 49 its (the standard height of a UITabBar as of this writing). Then it will look correct on devices with and without a safe area margin.

**Solution (part 2):** You will need to and manually adjust the `tableView.contentInset` / `collectionView.contentInset` to ensure content can scroll under the tab bar. You need to ensure the bottom-most item can still be scrolled up above the bottom tab bar:

1. Disable automatic content inset adjustment in your `viewDidLoad()`:

   ```
   tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
   ```
2. Adjust the `UIScrollView.contentInset` in an appropriate place, add the following method and call it either in `viewDidLoad()` or if necessary each time the view lays out in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. (If `viewDidLoad()` is too early for you, `viewWillAppear()` is probably too early, too.)

   ```
   private func adjustScrollViewInsets() {

       // This snippet only insets the bottom of the table view, but you may need to adjust both top and bottom edges if you also need to accommodate a top navigation bar.

       var contentInset = tableView.contentInset
       if let windowInsets = view.window ?? UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets {
           contentInset.bottom = windowInsets.bottom
       } else {
           contentInset.bottom = 0
       }
       tableView.contentInset = contentInset
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Tested on SWIFT 5.x**

After FAILING multiple times post :-

- **Implementing tabBar delegates**
- Setting **tabBarController viewControllers** array
- Implementing **tabBar selectedIndex** switch case

Finally came some clean hack/solution to mind..

1. Make new `UIViewController()` class
2. Assign it to relative tabBar item
3. `init()` existing View Controller from storyboard/xib
4. Push without animation on `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
   class FavouritesViewController: UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           guard let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController else { return }
           homeViewController.filterFavourites = true
           navigationController?.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: false)
       }
   }
   ```

To prevent back gesture navigation so that it won't pop to empty View Controller on left edge swipe

(OPTIONAL: Also hide navigationBar/Back button if applicable in `HomeViewController`)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true
}
```