# Convert storyboarded single view app to tabbed view with multiple of the same view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've nearly perfected my first iOS app as a single view using a storyboard in Xcode 5. Now I would like to include a tab bar with three copies of that *same* view. I.e. there will be three different data sets displayed in exactly the same way, selectable from the tabs.

I'm struggling with the approach to make this conversion. As I understand it all my model and controller code can remain identical (save for fetching the data unique to each) but I am lost as to whether I modify the storyboard or do it programatically.

The storyboard approach seems wrong as each view wants its own definition, when they should share the same. The code approach makes more sense but I am struggling with finding all the pieces to make it work. I've had a couple of goes and cannot get the tabbed view to even display when launched in the simulator.

I understand my existing view will need to shrink to fit but I have auto layout working, so that should take care of itself.

Just to clarify, I built the app from the "single view" template and am using the storyboard currently to launch and connect everything.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is. In the storyboard, you can copy and paste your one view controller multiple times, and connect them up to a tab bar controller. This will give you multiple instances of a single controller class. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: I didn't realise there was simple duplication available in the storyboard. If I duplicate my View Controller in the storyboard, does that mean if I want to change the structure of the view in future (which I will), I have to then do it in three places?

Comment: Actually, I think I found the answer on another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982721/how-to-connect-two-different-tab-bar-icons-to-same-view-controller-with-storyboa

Thanks for your comment as it helped me rephrase my question to find that.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment I left above, here's the solution I went with.

1. Attach the existing view controller to the tab bar controller by dragging.
2. Remove any default added views from the tab controller, leaving only mine.
3. Mark the tab controller as the initial view. (And unmark my original.)
4. Change my original view controller to cope with the space taken by the tab bar (in my case I don't want anything under it so I unticked "Under bottom bars".)
5. In my code, throw away the existing single attached view and instead establish three

Inside the app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method...

```
// Add extra tabs
UIViewController *vc1, *vc2, *vc3;
vc1 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CBViewController"];
[vc1 setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tab A" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabA_unselected"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabA_selected"]]];
vc2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CBViewController"];
[vc2 setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tab B" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabB_unselected"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabB_selected"]]];
vc3 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CBViewController"];
[vc3 setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tab C" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabC_unselected"] selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabC_selected"]]];
_tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[_tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, nil] animated:YES];
```